# Run activity before clicking a button

Tags: android, multithreading

I would like to implement this with a thread. But I do not know how to start
For example when opening a menu and before pressing an option, I run my activity so that, when you click on the option, all the data is already loaded, so that the user can see the data quickly without having to wait, someone could Help me with a small example?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Starting an `Activity` means you are creating a new Component (out of the 4 main Components in Android), and this means putting it on top of the back stack, and changing the UI to show it to the user. As far as I know, you cannot just "start" an `Activity` in the background. You could use a Fragment system where a Non-UI Fragment is used to do loading for prediction and then a new Fragment is shown on option click, but that makes for some troublesome decisions in terms of how to access the loaded data; unless it is an operation on global variables or on persistent data.

If you are talking about loading the UI elements up then no, that's not possible, that's not how Android works... the main work to load the UI is the rasterisation and GPU loading of the pixels you defined in xml files or programatically and must be done as you render the pixels themselves - no background work could do that.

If you are talking about loading up back-end data, then you could possibly create a separate class operating on a new `Thread` that does some work and puts it to a usable `ArrayList` or anything you want, then in the new `Activity` get a reference to them and avoid the load-times.

If your talking about predictive analytics where you predict what the user is going to choose and so load that data I don't know how to do that at all :)